# 2 Level Entity Folder in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a two level entity folder in a Symfony2 bundle:

```
CommonBundle/Entity/EntityFolder1/EntityA.php
CommonBundle/Entity/EntityFolder2
CommonBundle/Entity/EntityFolder3
CommonBundle/Entity/EntityFolder4
```

When I try to get the repositories for an entity that is within one of the folders:

```php
$product = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('CommonBundle:EntityA')->find(1);
```

Symfony doesn't recognize this `CommonBundle:EntityA`.

I also tried with `CommonBundle:EntityFolder1:EntityA`.

> Warning: class_parents(): Class CommonBundle\Entity\EntityA does not
>   exist and could not be loaded in

Comment: I don't think it is a good practice to create 2 folders in your Entity folder. There is actually nothing wrong in having the 2 entities in the same Entity folder. The path is easy to remember and you won't have to remember the folder they are in.

Comment: @Patt, it *is* a good practice to group related entities — and not entities only.

Comment: Thanks @elnur I din't know this at all! +1 for your answer. Many thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's `CommonBundle:EntityFolder1\EntityA`.

Comment: FYI: you may have to change your ORM yml file name as such: **EntityFolder1.EntityA.orm.yml**

Answer (score 1):

Use the full class name of your entity:

```
$product = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('Acme\CommonBundle\Entity\EntityFolder1\EntityA')
                ->find(1);
```