# Symfony2 - getRepository of entity on Entity subfolder

Tags: php, symfony, entity

Most of the time, entities are located at `src/Project/FooBundle/Entity/Foo.php`. Then you can access the repository by:

```
$this->getRepository('ProjectFooBundle:Foo');
```

But how to access the repository when an entity is located at `src/Project/FooBundle/Entity/Foo/Foo.php`?

Comment: try `$this->getRepository('ProjectFooBundle:Foo/Foo');`

Comment: Actually it's `$this->getRepository('ProjectFooBundle:Foo\Foo')`

Comment: @Touki i just think it's `/` not \`\\`, if i'm not wrong, back in the days i came across this issue :D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12336108/1607098

Answer (score 9, accepted):

as mentioned in my comment this can be done by the following syntax:

```
$this->getRepository('ProjectFooBundle:Foo/Foo');
```

or (as mentioned by @Touki)

```
$this->getRepository('ProjectFooBundle:Foo\Foo');
```

Comment: Is one only allowed to call ->getRepository([...]) on $this->getDoctrine() or can it be called on a controller-object? Since I get an error calling it on an controller-object, stating "call to undefined method".